# Extract string followed by specific word/symbol

Tags: shell-script, awk, ksh, xml

I have two lines as shown below in my input file input.txt and  I need to extract claimStartDate from first line and claimEndDate from second line.

```
<ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180409120000102" claimEndDate="2018-04-02" claimStartDate="2018-04-02" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">

<ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-17" claimStartDate="2018-04-17" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">

rm input.txt
awk '/<ProfessionalClaim/' test.xml | head -1 > input.txt
awk '/<ProfessionalClaim/' test.xml | tail -1 >> input.txt
awk '{match($0, "claimStartDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", start); print start[1]} \
     {match($0, "claimEndDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", end); print end[1]}' input.txt
```

Comment: Question needs to be completed.

Comment: F_LINE=<ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180409120000102" claimEndDate="2018-04-02" claimStartDate="2018-04-02" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">
L_LINE=<ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-17" claimStartDate="2018-04-17" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">

Comment: These lines are in a text file you want to use as the input? Are there multiple F_LINE and L_LINE? How should your output look like? Please edit your question and add these information. Use the code button to present file contents and commands better. Thanks!

Comment: I have pulled these two lines from XML file and use this as input to pull the claimStartDate from F_LINE & claimEndDate from L_LINE. I have changed the question now. Please let me know if need anymore details. thanks!

Comment: It would be appropriate and more efficient to use an XML parser (like XMLStarlet or a Perl/Python XML parser module) on _the original XML document_.  You have not shown how these lines are part of the original document or how you parse them out.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have option to use XML parser. I have used awk command to pull these lines from XML file.

Comment: Your file is not an XML file as it has no single root node. It would have been better to be able to work with whatever XML file these lines were extracted from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/F_LINE/ {match($0, "claimStartDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", start); print start[1]} \         
       /L_LINE/ {match($0, "claimEndDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", end); print end[1]}' input.txt
2018-04-02
2018-04-17
```

---

EDIT due to your new information:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {match($0, "claimStartDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", start); print start[1]} \            
       NR==2 {match($0, "claimEndDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", end); print end[1]}' input.txt
2018-04-02
2018-04-17
```

You can also do this all in one run:

```
$ grep "<ProfessionalClaim" text.xml \
| sed -n '1p;$p' \
| $ awk 'NR==1 {match($0, "claimStartDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", start); print start[1]} \            
         NR==2 {match($0, "claimEndDate=\"([^\"]+)\"", end); print end[1]}'
```

- `grep` find all line with `<ProfessionalClaim` in `text.xml`
- `sed` truncate the lines to the first and the last onyl
- `awk` will print the `claimStartDate` for the first line and `ClaimEndDate` for the second line

Comment: my inputs are in two string variable F_LINE & L_LINE. what is this input.txt here?

Comment: As you hasn't specify how you pulled the two lines I assumed they are in a new file called `input.txt` in my example. If this is not the case, provide more information in your original post, how you've extracted them and from where you start now. (show some code, what language are you using, ...)

Comment: Earlier I was writing those two lines in to separate variable each called F_LINE and L_LINE {<ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180409120000102" claimEndDate="2018-04-02" claimStartDate="2018-04-02" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">} {<ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-17" claimStartDate="2018-04-17" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00">}

Comment: I need only the claimStartDate from first line and claimEndDate from second line.

Comment: Thanks a lot it s working fine! Also need to take one other field from first and last line.(ClaimProcessedDateTime). I am using the below one for that, but for some reason the paid_stop not getting populated. grep "<ProfessionalClaim" test.xml \
| sed -n '1p;$p' \
|awk 'NR==1 {match($0, "claimProcessedDateTime=\"([^\"]+)\"", start); print "paid_start " start[1]} \ 
      NR==2 {match($0, "ClaimProcessedDateTime=\"([^\"]+)\"", end); print "paid_stop " end[1]}'

Comment: Take care of upper and lower cases. `ClaimProcessedDateTime` is not the same as `claimProcessedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some XML input document like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180409120000102" claimEndDate="2018-04-02" claimStartDate="2018-04-02" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00"/>
  <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-17" claimStartDate="2018-04-17" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00"/>
  <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-18" claimStartDate="2018-04-18" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00"/>
  <ProfessionalClaim paymentIndicator="P" claimProcessedDateTime="20180430120000281" claimEndDate="2018-04-19" claimStartDate="2018-04-19" sourceSystemId="abcd" claimActionCode="00"/>
</root>
```

... we may use `xmlstarlet` to extract the `claimStartDate` attribute's value from each `ProfessionalClaim` node that has another `ProfessionalClaim` node following it, together with that next `ProfessionalClaim` node's `claimEndDate` attribute's value:

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match '//ProfessionalClaim[following-sibling::ProfessionalClaim/@claimEndDate]' \
    --value-of 'concat(@claimStartDate, " ", following-sibling::ProfessionalClaim/@claimEndDate)' \
    -nl input.txt
```

This first matches each `ProfessionalClaim` node that is followed by another `ProfessionalClaim` node.

For each such node, the value of the `claimStartDate` attribute is concatenated with the value of the `claimEndDate` attribute of the following `ProfessionalClaim` node, with a single space character as delimiter.

Given my example document above, this would generate

```
2018-04-02 2018-04-17
2018-04-17 2018-04-18
2018-04-18 2018-04-19
```